# ASP.NET MVC5 Routing Error : works for one Action but not for the other

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have 3 actions; category, tag and search that has the same type of route signature but the routes start with different values.

Now only the category is working fine but the other two aren't.

Search action shows : `localhost/search?s=SOMEWORD` in the url and page loads.

But tag action gives me an error: `The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

I wanted my routes to be `localhost/{action}/{someWord}` but could not.

Controller Actions:

```
public ActionResult Category(string category, int p = 1)
    {
        //some caculations
        return View("List", viewModel);
    }


    public ActionResult Tag(string tag, int p = 1)
    {
        //some caculations
        return View("List", viewModel);
    }

    public ActionResult Search(string s, int p = 1)
    {
        //some caculations
        return View("List", viewModel);
    }
```

RouteConfig:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Category",
            "Category/{category}",
            new { controller = "Blog", action = "Category" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Tag",
            "Tag/{tag}",
            new { controller = "Blog", action = "Tag" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Search",
            "Search/{s}",
            new { controller = "Blog", action = "Search" }
        );
```

Comment: You can try with URL: localhost/Search?s=SOMEWORD

Comment: not i wont my url to be: localhost/Search/Someword..
and again the Tag action isn't working.